# Is there a "number" datatype in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am importing a database, in the read me that came with the csv, it describes he necessary table column names as well as the datatypes that should be used for each.

For one of the columns, the datatype "number" is used? My database client manager (HeidiSql) doesn't show any such option. The closest I see is enum. Is that what I should use?

Also no length was given in the description. If I should use enum what should I enter as length?

Comment: show an example of the data in that column, and they might be able to tell you which of mysql's numeric types is appropriate.

Comment: What is a "number" datatype? :( Do you mean NUMERIC or FLOAT or INT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several numeric types and also the enum type.

Comment: Of course ENUM doesn't have anything to do at all with numbers or numeric values...

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend `integer` if that number does not contain a decimal point, `float` or `double` if it does.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 2):

I think ***FLOAT or DECIMAL*** would be the best option because NUMBER datatype is not supported in MySQL.

Not recommending "**integer**" because you would get possible loss of precision of data

But in case if you are sure about *not losing data*, then go for ***bigint*** type in MySQL if the size of data is greater than 9 digits

> NUMBER datatype could be used in ORACLE SQL

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of all of the [MySQL numeric data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). It depends what type of numeric data you have as to which one you should use, Integers for whole numbers etc.

Enum is not a numeric type this is an [Enumeration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT` would be two options in MySQL.